# Inserting HTML documents into LibreOffice documents with outline numbering -- broken?

Tags: html, libreoffice, import, outline

I'm trying to import HTML into LibreOffice Writer. Apparently, it does not do well with outline numbering.

After setting up the numbering scheme in new document (in Tools > Outline numbering...), I use Insert > Document... and select an HTML file with this content:

```
<h1>Summary</h1>
<ol>
    <li>numbered</li>
    <li>items.</li>
</ol>
<h1>Stuff</h1>
<h1>Stuff2</h1>
```

The result is this:

[image]

Apparently, the numbered list confuses the importer for a bit.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what causes this, but adding an empty section to "recharge" section counting seems to do the trick:

```
<h1>Summary</h1>
<ol>
  <li>numbered</li>
  <li>items.</li>
</ol><h1></h1>
<h1>Stuff</h1>
<h1>Stuff2</h1>
```

[image]

*Nota bene:* This empty `<h1>` does not disturb subsection numbering. That is, if "Stuff" is an `<h2>` it gets the correct number 1.1.

Comment: I tested your HTML with both Firefox and Chrome. In neither case does it number the main headings. In Writer 5.1.4.2 insertion I got no numbers on the main headings, but `Stuff` was indented; the dummy heading made no difference. Was your master document ODT or HTML (though I didn't see a difference)?

Comment: @AFH I simply opened a new document in LibreOffice and set up Tools > Outline Numbering. Then, after pasting the HTML the headings are automatically numbered. ToCs can be created, too. Neater than I assumed it would be!

Comment: Intriguing. I have now reproduced your findings, and it seems not to matter whether outline numbering is applied before or after inserting, but I noticed another oddity/bug: the first heading has the correct font size and bold enhancement for the heading, but retains the default document font. If I start by opening the HTML document in Writer, rather than inserting it, the same font is used throughout, but I see the same quirk when I apply numbering.

Comment: I didn't even notice the font issue. Oh dear. X-)